# How to prove that $T_L(u) = T_L(w)$ implies that $u=w$?

Tags: group-theory, coxeter-groups

For a reduced decomposition $u=s_1 \cdots s_k$, $u \in W$, $W$ is a Coxeter group. $T_L(u)$ is defined as 
$$
T_L(u)=\{s_1 s_2 \cdots s_i \cdots s_2 s_1, 1 \leq i \leq k\}. \quad (1)
$$
I am trying to solve the exercis 11 on page 23 of the book [Combinatrics of Coxeter groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540442383).

How to prove that $T_L(u) = T_L(w)$ implies that $u=w$?

We can verify this for many examples. For example, if $u=s_1 s_2 s_1$, $w=s_2 s_1 s_2$, then we have 
$$
T_L(u)=\{s_1, s_1 s_2 s_1, s_1 s_2 s_1 s_2 s_1\} \\
=\{s_1, s_1 s_2 s_1, s_2 \} \\
T_L(w)=\{s_2, s_2 s_1 s_2, s_2 s_1 s_2 s_1 s_2\} \\
=\{s_2, s_1 s_2 s_1, s_1 \}.
$$
But how to prove (1) in general? Thank you very much.

Comment: When you write $u=w$, you presumably mean $u$ and $w$ represent the same element of $W$ rather than $u$ and $w$ are the same word?

Comment: @DerekHolt, yes.

Comment: I don't have this book at hand. But is it explained there why and if $T_L(u)$ is independent from the choice of the reduced expression of $u$?